# Dockerfile copy from build failing for create-react-app

Tags: docker, dockerfile, create-react-app

I have a react app I'm trying to dockerize for production. It was based off `create-react-app`. To run the app locally, I am in the app's root folder and I run `npm start`. This works. I built the app with `npm run build`. Then I try to create the docker image with `docker build . -t app-name`. This is failing for not being able to find the folder I'm trying to copy the built app from (I think).

Here's what's in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /src
ENV PATH /node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I'm pretty sure I've got something wrong on the `COPY --from` line.

The app structure is like this, if it matters

```
-app-name (folder)
  -src (folder)
  -build (folder)
  -dockerfile
  -other stuff, but I think I listed what matters
```

The error I get is `failed to compute cache key: "/build" not found: not found`

I'm running my commands in windows powershell.

What do I need to change?

Comment: try `COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost correct,
Just that the path where the `build` folder is generated is at `/src/build` and not at `/build`.
and hence the error you see,
and why the `/src` coming?
it's due to the `WORKDIR /src`.

and hence this should work: `COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html`

besides, since you are using `nginx` server to serve the build static files,
you don't need to or you cant run `npm start` with `CMD`.

instead, just leave it, and you can access the application at port `80`.

so the possible working Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /src
ENV PATH /node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

This is in accordance with the Dockerfile in the above question,
in some specific cases, advanced configuration might be required.